# Microphone problem

Tags: microphone

Microphone on my laptop is detected on every application and working. But, I'm trying to configure it to someone can hear me louder but with no luck. Also, people feedbacks me as I'm having robotic voice. I tried everything, also used pulseaudio and other but nothing worked.
Please help me,
Luka

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try checking the levels in `alsamixer` and also in `pavucontrol`.  A weird timbre can sometimes result from weird levels, so try that first.